# Using parent() and other functions, remove a div from a list

Tags: javascript, html

I am looking to create a chart that generates a series of rows.  Each row contains various buttons and text boxes.  The row in question is this.  Yes, I am using a bunch of divs instead of a list.  No, I'm not going to change it at this time as I'm strictly hacking this stuff together so it works, not so it's semantically usable.  This is an internal tool, intended for internal use only, and doesn't need to be perfectly semantic, nor does it need to be used by screen readers.  I've also removed irrelevant information/names/labels/classes.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="rcColumn">
    <button></button>
  </div>
  <div class="accColumn">
    <input></input>
    <button>Copy</button>
  </div>
  <div class="dollarColumn">
    <input></input>
    <button>Copy</button>
  </div>
  <div class="toolbar">
    <button>Clear</button>
    <button id="deleteLineButton" onclick="deleteLine();" title="Delete this line">X</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Yes, I'm aware it's not really good to use onclick in the HTML tags, but I am because again, whipping this up quick.  I slowly make things more and more clean over time but for now I'm making it work.  Don't kill me over it.

That said, the function I made is as follows:

```
function deleteLine() {
  $("#deleteLineButton").parent().parent().remove();
}
```

Now, there are functions I created that make a new line, effective adding that HTML exactly underneath.  It works fine.  However, while deleteLine() appropriately deletes the topmost div in the HTML example, it always goes for the topmost line, no matter how many new lines I make.

I tried making an alternate version like so:

```
function deleteLine() {
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
}
```

But that doesn't work either.  I also tried using "this" instead (with quotes), but still no dice.  The delete line button no longer works, and I get no error in the console.

I don't want to use IDs or Classes because I might make an arbitrary amount of lines.  How can I better select the appropriate row?  Was I on the right track using 'this'?

Comment: What does "the appropriate row" mean?

Comment: There is no explicit `this` in an onclick function. You have to pass in a reference to the element. Then you can't repeat ID either so using id selector will always target first matching id in page

Comment: clicks give an event object which can be processed as ```event.target.parent().parent().remove()```

Comment: @Pointy, the appropriate row means that batch of HTML code; there's a function that essentialls inserts multiple divs with the class "row".  My issue was that the top 'row' always got deleted, instead of whichever row contained the clicked button.

Comment: @charlietfl I keep struggling with the use of 'this', and only just started being able to use it, so I appreciate the heads up!

Comment: @sloont I'll keep that in mind, though there seemed to be a better suggestion down below.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the button id to a class since ids must be unique

```
<button class="deleteLineButton" title="Delete this line">X</button>
```

Then rather than using outdated inline onclick you can add a jQuery event listener that traverses to `closest('.row')` which is more understandable to read than chaining `parent().parent()`

```
$('.deleteLineButton').on('click', function(){
    $(this).closest('.row').remove()
})
```

Comment: So I use .appnendTo() to add all of that HTML.  Using your code, the first line that already exists works fine, however, any subsequent line that gets generated does not work; and I made sure it's the same tags and text that was in the original HTML document.  No errors thrown in the console, either.

Comment: Try delegating... `$(document).on('click', '.deleteLineButton', function()...` Accounts for elements that are inserted in the future

Comment: Fantastic!  That did the trick!  Thank you so very much!  If I may ask, what makes this work, over the jquery code in your original answer?

Comment: See [Understanding Event Delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: Short answer is my original version only works for elements that exist at the time the code is run

Comment: I was suspecting that was the case, but felt really silly saying it.  I should know better than to second guess.  Thank you again!

Comment: No worries. Takes time to learn a lot of the nuances